# How can I transform equation results into an array of values?

Tags: list-manipulation, assignment

I would like some help. I executed the following code:

```
Solve[Det[(s IdentityMatrix[2]) - A] == 0]
```

which yielded the following results at the output:

```
{{s -> -5 i}, {s -> 5 i}}
```

Now I would like to save the results in a number of expressions, which will be equal to the number of different results, and I would like to achieve that using an array which can hold complex and real numbers. The aim is to be able to run a few checks on the results.

Can someone here help me out?

Comment: This is an [eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors), try `s=Eigenvalues[A]`

Comment: i know that command, but what i want is to assign the results to an array.
will this line do the trick?

Comment: So you want to go from the list: sol = {{s -> -5 i}, {s -> 5 i}}; to the list {-5 I,5 I}? If so, you can just index into the sol array using: sol[[All, 1, 2]]. Or you can use: s /. sol

Comment: let me ask a different question: how can i run a check if the real part of every number in {a,b} is smaller then zero?

Comment: @bitmetvt I think you need some practice reading the documentation...check out `Re`, `Eigenvalues`, etc. It'll save you time in the long run if you can find this stuff yourself

Comment: i already went through the documentation and am familiar with Re and Eigenvalues, thats not the issue here. w= Eigenvalues gives the output {5i+s,-5i+s}. im having trouble with for[i=0,i<Length@w, i++,If[Real[w[i]]<0,counter1++,counter2++]]
the counters are set to zero at the begining and nothing changes after the loop.
either i cant access each root in w, or something else is wrong here.

Comment: Maybe `Select[sol, Re[s /. #] < 0 &]`? Or `Select[eigs, Negative@Re@# &]` if `eigs = Eigenvalues[A]` or `eigs = s /. sol` (from @bills's comment)? [Note on previous comment: If you got `{5i+s,-5i+s}`, you didn't use `Eigenvalues` the way @ yarchik indicated.

Comment: `evs = GroupBy[Eigenvalues[mat], Sign@*Re]` is also a nice way to collect the results. The counts are given by `Length /@ evs`, or if you don't want to save `evs`, you can directly compute them with `CountsBy[Eigenvalues[mat], Sign@*Re]`. Note: Using `Sign` will count EVs with zero real part separately from ones with pos./neg. parts; use `Negative` instead of `Sign` to separate into neg./nonneg.

Answer (score 1):

Set the output of `Solve` equal to a variable. I am going to use lower case for the matrix `A` as upper case symbols can collide with system symbols.

```
aMatrix = {{5 I/2, 0}, {0, -5 I/2}}
sol = Solve[Det[(s*IdentityMatrix[2]) - aMatrix] == 0]
{{s -> -((5 I)/2)}, {s -> (5 I)/2}}
```

Now we will use `ReplaceAll` (shortcut `/.`) to get a vector for the solution

```
sVector = s /. sol
{-((5 I)/2), (5 I)/2}
```

Hope this helps.